# Push simple array indexes into multidimensional array where indexes are empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently have two arrays. The first array `randomString` is a list of various text strings.
The second array `images` contains the "end-structure" of the array im looking to work with.
In my second array, some indexes are empty.

**Im looking to push text strings from my first array `randomString` into the second array `images` that have an empty index.**

Im really not sure what approach would be the best for this. I figured I could loop through the images array and look for the empty indexes and somehow push. Guess I got stuck at the push part.

Any suggestions?

```
for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
  if(images[0][i][3] == "") {
    //push??
  }
}
```

The first array looks like this:

```
var randomString=new Array(
    "Random string 4",
    "Random string 88",
    "Random string 636",
    "Random string 99",
    "Random string 344",
    "Random string 233",
    "Random string 12",
    "Random string 23"
);
```

And the second array is a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
var images=new Array([
    ["image1.png","10", "Name 1", "pre-determined-random-string 1"],
    ["image2.png","26", "Name 2", ""],
    ["image3.png","39", "Name 3", "pre-determined-random-string 2"],
    ["image4.png","40", "Name 4", ""]
    ["image5.png","11", "Name 5", ""]
]);
```

Comment: And by pushing you mean add a string to the destination and removing it from the source (randomString)?

Comment: Adding to the destination would be sufficient. If it doesn't do much performance'wise it could be cool to see how you remove from randomStrings and add to images, but it is not a must at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to re assign the array value, not `push` 
Could do something like:

```
/* make copy of array in case we need more strings than array contains*/
var stringsArray=randomString.slice();

for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
  if(images[i][3] == "") {
    if( !stringsArray.length){
      stringsArray=randomString.slice();    
    }
    /* take last string from array*/
    images[i][3]=stringsArray.pop()
  }
}
```

Note that you are adding an extra array nesting needlessly. Above is based on following structure

```
var images=[
    ["image1.png","10", "Name 1", "pre-determined-random-string 1"],
    ......
];
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fY4bF/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: You're brilliant - works just as supposed! and thanks for pointing out the extra array nesting - removed that now also - appreciate the effort!